# How to remove a rogue extension labelled “Installed by enterprise policy”?

Tags: google-chrome, search-engine

I found a rogue extension (likely malware?) that I cannot removed, as the delete icon is greyed out and the extension says "installed by enterprise policy".

It also changed my default search and default home page from google.com to www.arabyonline.com.

I have tried running  Anti-Malware softwares - none of these removed it.

I also tried to uninstall and re install chrome but it did not work.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: It is all available from options. This question is really wrong and shows no research effort from you.

Comment: I tried to change the search engine from settings in chrome but I get this message. "This setting is enforced by your administrator". I cannot change the search engine sites.

Comment: Do you have an administrator access on your machine? You didn't provide enough information.

Comment: I am the only user and I am the administrator. It seems to some kind of malware.

Comment: The answer http://superuser.com/questions/709711/how-to-remove-a-rogue-extension-labelled-installed-by-enterprise-policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's probably happening because you're infected with malware

Here's your way to go:

[Support Google : Remove ads, search engine, homepage, and extensions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2765944?hl=en)

Which was also my first hit in Google.

[Google forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/4lSv8YrGzeQ)

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I did follow your instructions to reach to this page https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/IkbJXYMH4Ds/7AzMdLHhixoJ but i did not find any solution.

Comment: Have you already done everything they say in the first link? If yes, and this doesn't seem to help - you will need to go deeper into `regedit`

Comment: I even deleted the google folder in software/google/chrome in regedit as they mentioned but it didnot work for me.

Comment: I found the answer . I just followed C Crawford advice .Thanks for ur replies.http://superuser.com/questions/709711/how-to-remove-a-rogue-extension-labelled-installed-by-enterprise-policy

Comment: Great. You may add your answer or update the question with solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

first , do a Scan by an anti-malware program.

second, start menu right click then click run and type regedit then hit enter find HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE double click "software" then double click "policies" then double click "Microsoft" then double click "Internet explorer" then click "main" this will show the "start page" right click then click "modify" put what web page you like.
do the same for chrome in the same path

third , Delete this file C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\registry.pol
and you will be ok

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! Unfortunately that question is off topic for Stack Overflow to begin with - see the [help] for what's on topic here and what's not.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple to remove it, start menu right click then click run and type regedit then hit enter
find HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE double click "software" then double click "policies" then double click "Microsoft" then double click "Internet explorer" then click "main" this will show the   "start page" right click then click "modify" put what web pge you like...goodluck